# Can Chang'e 3 take photos of the stars from the moon

Tags: the-moon, astronomy, chang-e

Chang'e 3 now on the Lunar surface has imaged the Earth. Is it possible for that same camera to take a time exposure and show us the stars?

Comment: It is equipped with a UV telescope, [LUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_3#Lunar-based_ultraviolet_telescope_.28LUT.29)  to observe stars among other objects.

Answer (score 3):

Looking through [this image archive](http://moon.bao.ac.cn/multimedia/img2dce3.jsp), they haven't taken photos where stars are the main subject. All photos in that archive were done in daylight.

[image: Chang'e 3 photo of Earth]

I've removed the processed photo - I found 2 bright pixels in the shadowed region of the Earth, so those can't possibly be stars.

Chang'e 3 [hibernates](http://spaceflight101.com/change/change-3/) during the lunar night. It's [not clear](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/c-missions/chang-e-3) if the probe contains an RTG that can provide electrical power, or if it has radionucleide heaters only.

> The majority of power provided by the RTG is used for the heaters and a small fraction is used to sustain the lander's Lunar Night Sleep Mode in which all systems except for crucial control and housekeeping systems are shut down.

I tried to find out a bit more about the [camera](http://spaceflight101.com/change/change-3/):

> Three panoramic cameras are installed on the lander, facing different
>   directions to allow the lander to acquire images of the lunar terrain
>   surrounding the landing site and take photos of the rover as it
>   departs the landing site. The cameras can take still images as well as
>   video. *Exact technical details for the cameras were not released*. (emphasis mine)
>
> Camera technology tested on previous missions that is employed on
>   Chang’e 3 include auto-exposure, focus adjustments, high-speed
>   compression of color imagery and static gray image, and sub-sampling
>   methods.

I also found a paper ([PDF](https://www.raa-journal.org/docs/papers_accepted/ms1939.pdf.gz)) that analyzes the performance of the cameras on Yutu in more detail. It doesn't mention exposure times specifically. It does say the camera has both manual and automatic exposure modes. The PDF contains a few graphs that show camera performance, these have an X-axis marked 0-1200 with a label of "0.5 ms". I think that means the X-axis shows an exposure time of 0-0.6 seconds, but I'm not entirely sure. If this is true, the camera has been designed to use exposures of up to 0.6 s, which sounds long enough to see a few stars.

[image: Yutu camera performance]

**Edit**:

More information on the Chang'e 3 image archive can be found in these blog posts:
[one](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2016/01281656-fun-with-a-new-data-set-change.html)
[two](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/2016/01221450-china-invites-public-on-board.html)

The archive itself is [here](http://moon.bao.ac.cn/ceweb/datasrv/datadesclevel.jsp) but is available in Chinese only.

Comment: The bright spots in the image are most likely hot pixels of the image sensor and no real stars. Easy to spot: Most are fully saturated colors of single pixels. A star should show up as a slightly blurry spot of several pixels due to the finite resolution of the optics.

Comment: Good point, I've removed the photo.

Comment: Looking at the camera specs, do you think  it is capable of imaging the stars? Daylight should make no difference to the camera as long as it is not looking at the Sun, stars should show up with a few seconds exposure time.

Comment: It seems the Chinese space agency hasn't published details on the camera specs.

Comment: Is that image archive still available? I can't seem to get a connection from where I am.

Comment: The archive is still available, but can take a while to come up, connections from overseas can be unreliable. I've also added some new links at the end of the post.